# Apache rewrite rule to lowercase directory only

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule that will only apply the lowercase to the directories (Not the filename)

With the help of the apache manual, I've got this far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*) ${lc:$1}
```

But obviously this is going to apply to the whole uri. I have tried a whole lot of different regex's and RewriteConditions, but regex really gives me a headache, and was wondering if someone could help.

Just to confirm, I'd want this:

```
http://www.anything.any/AnYpatH/iN/Site/FiLeNaMe.ExT
```

to rewrite to:

```
http://www.anything.any/anypath/in/site/FiLeNaMe.ExT
```

Comment: try this `RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([^\/]+)$ ${lc:$1}/$2 [L]` . If it works then add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]` upper

Comment: That's really weird, it works for anything.com/MixEDcasE/filename.ext but not anything.com/ALLUPPER/filename.ext

Comment: they recommended [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to capture the path and the filename as separate groups. The path is going to be everything up to the final slash `/`, while the filename will be everything after that. This could be accomplished with the following regex ([see demo **here**](https://regex101.com/r/lF9dO0/1)):

```
(.*?[A-Z].*\/)(.*)
```

Then you'll want to do the following (apologies if I don't have the `.htaccess` syntax just right):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z].*\/)(.*) ${lc:$1}$2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This mostly works, but for some reason, if the directory is entered in all upper case, the browser adds a trailing slash to the filename ...

Comment: Yep, using this, plus a trailing space rewrite rule it works :D ... Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so: `https?:\/\/.+?\/(.*?[A-Z]+.*)\/` this will match `AnYpatH/iN/Site` in its capturing group.

A working example of the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/iN8rD5/1).